# SelectOneMenu not displayed correctly

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I would appreciate some input on the following issue:

I got one login screen followed by another page with a `Panel` and inside this `Panel` a `SelectOneMenu`. Unfortunatly the output of the `SelectOneMenu` after login is sometimes like this:

[image: SelectOneMenu Bug]

*Instead the full(!) name of the User should be placed in the middle of the `SelectOneMenu`.* 
*Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.*
*Also if I switch `User` now, I only get the first letter of it. (Inside the dropdown the full name is written tho)*

I populate the content inside a `ManagedBean` (`@ViewScoped`) in it's `PostConstruct` and get the data from database. (View -> ManagedBean -> DAO class -> ManagedBean).
I also tried to put the code inside `public Classname{}` with the same result.

I think there is a problem with the `SelectOneMenu` not correctly being rendered.
How to fix that?

users.xhtml:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="somSelect" value="#{userManagerBean.somValue}"
    styleClass="selecters">
    <p:ajax update="userDataTable" listener="#{userManagerBean.changeSomValue}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{userManagerBean.userList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

ManagedBean @ViewScoped:

```
   @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
    // DAO Method
            retrieveTableData();

            String loggedInUser = "";
            try{
            loggedInUser = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("sprintUser").toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("> No previous login");
            }

            // Check for session login name and select from table - if session null select first
            if (somValue == null && userList.size() != 0) {
                somValue = userList.get(0);             
                for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++){                           
                    if(loggedInUser.equals(userList.get(i))){
                        somValue = loggedInUser;
                    }
                }       
            }               

            selectedUser = somValue();       
            userData = new ArrayList<User>();
// a Table population
            populateUser(userData);
        }
```

Comment: maybe we can see some code?

Comment: If you want to show the logged user name initially, could you try to add this into selectonemenu `<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{userManagerBean.loggedUserName}" itemValue="" />` then you can use `f:selectItems` to show other items with rest of the list.

Comment: No I don't want to do that but thanks for the hint.

Comment: I would guess that there is a problem inside your code but to be able to spot it you will have to show more code and/or strip the code down to the necessary parts (i.e provide a small example that shows the problem). E.g. what does `populateUser()` do?
(Did you verify that this problem occurs consistently throughout different browsers?)

Comment: Only tested it with chrome and most often only happens when DB-retrieving is slower than average.